# Divergence and Covariant/Contravariant Transformations

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, covariance

I am trying to understand the covariant/contravariant representation of the divergence in different coordinate systems.

Normally, we would get in the holonomic basis the following divergence according to wikipedia:

$$
\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{E} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{det(g)}}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\left(\sqrt{det(g)}E^i \right)}
$$

But I can also write it in terms of the covariant components:

$$
\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{E} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{det(g)}}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\left(\sqrt{det(g)}\cdot g^{ij}E_j \right)}
$$

My first question would be: what is exactly the meaning of the notation with the covariant components?

If I have a vector, e.g.:

$$
\vec{E}=\begin{pmatrix} E^1 \\ E^2 \\ E^3 \end{pmatrix}
$$

I just plug in the values of my contravariant components in my first "contravariant version" of the divergence.
But what is the meaning of the components $E_i$, if we want to calculate the divergence with them ?

My second question would be regarding the normalized contravariants and covariants components for **orthogonal** basis.

$$
E^i = \frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{ii}}}\hat{E}^i
$$
and
$$
E^i=g^{ii}E_i=\frac{1}{g_{ii}}E_i= \frac{1}{g_{ii}}\cdot\sqrt{g_{ii}}\hat{E}_i = \frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{ii}}}\hat{E}_i
$$

Does it imply, that normalized covariant components are equal to the normalized contravariant components of orthogonal bases? Does it also hold for non-orthogonal bases?

Comment: *What is exactly the meaning of the notation with the covariant components?* Do you understand the Einstein summation convention? If so, what do you not understand about the notation?

Comment: Your first formula is called Voss-Weyl formula and -as you say- uses contravariant components in a holonomic (aka coordinate) basis. When you switch $E^i$ to $g^{ij}E_j$ nothing new happens. It is just a more complicated notation. I know how to go from holonomic to orthogonal basis by normalizing the vectors but I have trouble to reconcile your later formulas with the summation convention (too many same indices). Anyway: whatever you do to replace the original $E^i$ makes the Voss-Weyl formula just more complicated. Nothing can change that divergence it computes.

Comment: *My second question…* Please ask one question per post. Otherwise, your post may get closed for being unfocused.

Comment: Do you understand how covariant and contravariant components are related? Given a metric, you can express either in terms of the other. Both sets of components are equally valid ways to represent a vector.

Comment: Yes, I understand the Einstein summation convention behind it, but it is for me hard to grasp the ideia of representing a vector with covariant components. When would someone use the second representation of the divergence, since we usually represent vectors with the contravariant components? Almost never, right?